# Spring Boot datasorurce configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource, spring-jdbc

Below is the `*.yml` file for one of our application

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    username: user1
    password: pass1
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host1:port1:sid1
    tomcat:
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
      username: user2
      password: pass2
      url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host2:port2:sid2
      max-active: 10
      default-transaction-isolation: 2 
  main:
    banner-mode: log
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

I am just wondering which database will Spring pick by `JdbcTemplate` and what is the difference between these two?

Comment: If not specified otherwise, it will use the first set (spring.datasource.url, etc.) But you can tell it to use the other prefix (spring.datasource.tomcat.*).

Comment: There is only 1 datasource configured here. The `spring.datasource.tomcat` will only be used if you use the `tomcat-jdbc` connection pool to configure the used connection pool specific settings (like max-active etc.).  The default is `HikariCP` so generally those will be ignored, unless you choose to use the `tomcat-jdbc` one.

Answer (score 2):

Sring will get these configuration

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    username: user1
    password: pass1
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host1:port1:sid1
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties

Comment: `driverClasName` and `driver-class-name` are the same. Spring Boot is relaxed in that binding.